# Unable to use webmin outside my LAN: UBUNTU SERVER on VMWARE

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-server, webmin

I have a windows PC

I have installed Ubuntu server on my Vmware and switched to Bridge Network

Now I installed webmin

sudo service webmin start

with ssl=1

also done this

sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT

I can access webmin from my computer and on my LAN

[image]

also via browser on any device on my wifi https://192.168.187.129:10000/

[image]

But I cannot access this from outside network

[image]

[image]

But i cannot use this outside of my lan.

I can connect with ssh on my lan only

also done sudo ufw allow 10000

No answer on this

https://superuser.com/questions/1122496/cant-acces-webmin-outside-the-virtual-machine-running-it-virtualbox-ubuntu-s

Comment: most likely 192.168.187.XX is host only virtual network and nodes on your physical LAN can't access your virtual lan . You need to use [bridged networking](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_net_configurations_changing_bridged_windows.html) to expose network adapter of guest into physical LAN.

Comment: Thank You, switching to bridging helped me to run in the whole lan but not globally, how to switch it globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable port forwarding on your router.  192.168 is reserved for internal networks and cannot be routed across the Internet.  Your router will have it's on external IP address and you will need to enable port forwarding so that when you hit externalIP:10000 it gets forwarded to 192.168.187.129:10000.

Of course, this will mean that Webmin is exposed to anyone on the Internet who wants to try to log in, so make sure you set strong passwords.  You may want to consider locking it down so that only a subset of external IP's can connect as well.